# node js syntaxError: Unexpected Identifier

Tags: node.js

There are a lot of questions regarding this issue, but none of them were helpful, as they fix a concrete syntax error. I'm really new in Javascript programming, starting it a few weeks ago. 
I would like to run my scripts on Node.js, but for some reason it is not working. It gives me the next error: `SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`
I'm talking about very simple scripts, like this:

```
 var orders =[
  {amount: 250 },
  {amount: 400 },
  {amount: 100 },
  {amount: 325 },
 ];
  var totalAmount=0
  for(var i=0; i< orders.length; i++){

   totalAmount+=orders[i].amount;

   }

  console.log(totalAmount);
```

What basically is working on my browser smoothly.
I'm really sorry to bother you with such small silly things, but I would appreciate any help. It's easier to work with  my scripts on node js.

Comment: Can you post the actual error and the script that produces it.

Comment: the script you posted works, can you provide more info, so that we can help

Comment: Hi Nikhil, thanks for replying . The problem I can't run the script in node.js, because it gives the next error:" SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" .I tried to open it through command prompt , but then nothing happens. I'm really new in this world, so it can be some silly issue, the scripts I'm making are working nice in google chromes console , but the node doesn't like it for some reason.

Comment: Jack, thanks for your time. The scripts are very simple exercises like the one above, I just jumped in javascript. The scripts are working in browser, but the node.js  gives the error what I mentioned, with no any other detail, just that line.

Answer (score 0):

How are you running your scripts in nodejs? If you are just starting with js, try it in browser. Or if you really want it with nodejs.

1. Download the Windows executable here: http://nodejs.org/#download
2. Copy the file to C:\
3. Create C:\hello.js
4. Paste in the following content:

   ```
   var http = require('http');
   http.createServer(function (req, res) {
     res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
     res.end('Hello World\n');
   }).listen(1337, "127.0.0.1");
   console.log('Server running at 127.0.0.1:1337');
   ```

   1. Save the file
   2. Start -> Run... -> cmd
   3. c: C:>node hello.js

Comment: I've tried it ,nothing really happens, I press enter and that's it, no any reply. My node is installed in program files by default, I guess that cannot be a problem.Before I was thinking maybe is some mess with my localhost folder, but now i can see that is not working neither in different folders. I keep looking for documentation about it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I've got the problem, I tried to run the things through the language shell window instead of node.js command prompt.It's silly I know, but it wasn't specified where to run the node commands. By the way I found out more, then I was expecting. I don't regret to register here, you have a lot of material here. Thank you guys.
I hope one day I can help out someone.